# Looking for help mass updating/appending value in on column based on values in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a user ID column and an email column that has the same constant value. I'm trying to update that email column with the respective user id's appended to the front of the email value. There are thousands of records so this would need to be bulk update if possible. So the end result would be 1email, 2email, 3email, etc. (see screenshot)

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVZwo.png)

Comment: Something like this? `UPDATE YourTable SET Email = cast([UserID] as varchar) + [Email]`

Comment: I would suggest `CONCAT` would be better choice than using `CAST` with a `varchar` with an undefined length.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this worked for you in the comments I figured I'd add it as an answer so you can close the question

`UPDATE YourTable SET Email = cast([UserID] as varchar) + [Email]`